# Print repeating headers after 1st page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok, so I have done a LOT of research and can't find anything. Here is what I have. I need to create a print button, and the print view needs to have repeating headers after the 1st page. AKA, the 1st page's header is different than the rest of the pages. As of now, this is what I have, but it repeats on every page and I can't make a custom 1st page header. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .section {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .section > div {
        display: table-cell;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .section ~ .section > div:before {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: -2.5em; /* inverse of header height */
      }
      .section > div > div {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        vertical-align: top;
      }
      .header {
        height: 2.5em; /* header must have a fixed height */
      }
      .content { /* this rule set just adds space between sections and is not required */
        margin-bottom: 1.25em;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="section">
      <div>
        <div>
          <div class="header">
            PAGE HEADER
          </div>
          <div class="content">
            Unbreakable section.<br/>Unbreakable section.<br/>Unbreakable section.<br/>
            Unbreakable section.<br/>Unbreakable section.<br/>Unbreakable section.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <div>
        <div>
          <div class="header">
            PAGE HEADER
          </div>
          <div class="content">
            Unbreakable section.<br/>Unbreakable section.<br/>Unbreakable section.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <div>
        <div>
          <div class="header">
            PAGE HEADER
          </div>
          <div class="content">
            Unbreakable section.<br/>Unbreakable section.<br/>Unbreakable section.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <div>
        <div>
          <div class="header">
            PAGE HEADER
          </div>
          <div class="content">
            Unbreakable section.<br/>Unbreakable section.<br/>Unbreakable section.<br/>
            Unbreakable section.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <div>
        <div>
          <div class="header">
            PAGE HEADER
          </div>
          <div class="content">
            Unbreakable section.<br/>Unbreakable section.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <div>
        <div>
          <div class="header">
            PAGE HEADER
          </div>
          <div class="content">
            Unbreakable section.<br/>Unbreakable section.<br/>Unbreakable section.<br/>
            Unbreakable section.<br/>Unbreakable section.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <div>
        <div>
          <div class="header">
            PAGE HEADER
          </div>
          <div class="content">
            Unbreakable section.<br/>Unbreakable section.<br/>Unbreakable section.<br/>
            Unbreakable section.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <div>
        <div>
          <div class="header">
            PAGE HEADER
          </div>
          <div class="content">
            Unbreakable section.<br/>Unbreakable section.<br/>Unbreakable section.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <div>
        <div>
          <div class="header">
            PAGE HEADER
          </div>
          <div class="content">
            Unbreakable section.<br/>Unbreakable section.<br/>Unbreakable section.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <div>
        <div>
          <div class="header">
            PAGE HEADER
          </div>
          <div class="content">
            Unbreakable section.<br/>Unbreakable section.<br/>Unbreakable section.<br/>
            Unbreakable section.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <div>
        <div>
          <div class="header">
            PAGE HEADER
          </div>
          <div class="content">
            Unbreakable section.<br/>Unbreakable section.<br/>Unbreakable section.<br/>
            Unbreakable section.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <div>
        <div>
          <div class="header">
            PAGE HEADER
          </div>
          <div class="content">
            Unbreakable section.<br/>Unbreakable section.<br/>Unbreakable section.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <div>
        <div>
          <div class="header">
            PAGE HEADER
          </div>
          <div class="content">
            Unbreakable section.<br/>Unbreakable section.<br/>Unbreakable section.<br/>
            Unbreakable section.<br/>Unbreakable section.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, another edit. You should be able to override JUST the first section page header using `body > .section > div:before` and all others page headers with `.section ~ .section > div:before`.

Fiddle updated. When I print this in chrome I get 'First page header' on the first page, nothing on any of the sections until the first section of subsequent pages. You loose the margin on the first page header, so you may need to tweak the spacing.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1hkzrL33/2/)

```
body > .section > div:before {
  content: "First Page Header";
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: -2.5em;
}

.section ~ .section > div:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: -2.5em; /* inverse of header height */
}
```

Comment: This gets me a little closer, however It doesn't print this way. The "PAGE HEADER" still appears at the top of each page when you print. I would like to see something different on the second page. Please let me know if I am just not seeing it lol

Comment: Ahhh, I see what you're trying to do. I don't think that's possible just changing the CSS. I take it you can't add markup just to the first page header? Aka: http://jsfiddle.net/1hkzrL33/1/

Comment: Okay, is there any way you think I can accomplish this goal without CSS?

Comment: Ok, made another edit after thinking about this some more. As for alternatives, theres always creating a pdf programmatically and printing that, which would give you a lot more control, but also be a huge amount of overhead, depending on how important this task is.